# Writing debug data to new table on new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large table that I need to identify when the value in the column "Pass Num" changes.
So far I have this

```
Sub loopTableRowsInAColumnListObject()

    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim lRow As Range

    Set lo = Sheets("Sheet3").ListObjects(1)

    Debug.Print "LISTOBJECT APPROACH - FOR EACH LOOP"
    Debug.Print "-----------------------------------"


    For Each lRow In lo.ListColumns("Pass Num").DataBodyRange.Rows
        If lRow.Offset(0, 0).Value2 <> lRow.Offset(-1, 0).Value2 Then
            Debug.Print lRow.Row & vbTab & lRow.Value2 & vbTab & lRow.Offset(0, -24) & vbTab & lRow.Offset(0, -22) & vbTab & lRow.Offset(0, -11)
        End If

    Next lRow

    Debug.Print "-----------------------------------"

End Sub
```

This writes to the intermediate window the values I require but I would like to write these to a new table on a new worksheet so a can call them back in to manipulate the table.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Probably better to do this in memory with a `Variant` array.... why do you need to "call them back in"?

Comment: I need to identify the start and end of each pass "pass num" but the pass number can repeat itself. ie. 20 rows of pass num = 1, 20 rows of pass num = 2, 20 rows of pass num = 1 again.

Comment: You should be able to do that in memory instead of writing these to a temporary table in the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this
'''
Sub loopTableRowsInAColumnListObject()

```
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim lRow As Range
Dim arr() As Variant

Set lo = Sheets("Sheet3").ListObjects(1)


With lo.DataBodyRange
tRows = .Rows.Count
tCols = .Columns.Count
End With

Dim i As Long
Dim c As Long 'number of passes
c = 0

'Debug.Print lo.DataBodyRange.Cells(2, lo.ListColumns("Pass num").Index)

For i = 1 To tRows
   If lo.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, lo.ListColumns("Pass num").Index) <> lo.DataBodyRange.Cells(i - 1, lo.ListColumns("Pass num").Index) Then
   c = c + 1
   'Debug.Print lo.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, lo.ListColumns("Pass num").Index) & vbTab & c & vbTab & i
   End If
Next i

' reDeclare an array to hold marks for c
ReDim arr(c, 2)

c = 0

For i = 1 To tRows
   If lo.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, lo.ListColumns("Pass num").Index) <> lo.DataBodyRange.Cells(i - 1, lo.ListColumns("Pass num").Index) Then
   c = c + 1
   ''Debug.Print lo.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, lo.ListColumns("Pass num").Index) & vbTab & c & vbTab & i
   arr(x, 0) = c
   arr(x, 1) = i
   x = x + 1
   End If
Next i

' Print results from the array to the Immediate Window
Debug.Print "results"
For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
   Debug.Print arr(x, 0) & vbTab & arr(x, 1)
Next x
```

End Sub
'''

It looks through a column in a table "lo".

the counter "c" is for every time the "Pass Num" changes.

Counter "i" is the row number that that change happens.

These are placed in an array "arr"